# How do you install flash debug version with Windows 10

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript, windows-10

I have been looking for a way to install the debug version of flashplayer for ie11 or the newer microsoft edge browser under Windows 10. AS far as I understand, the flash plugin is now embedded with both browsers, so there is no way to update it to a debug version.
Using the debug version installer from adobe site (active x version), gives me a pop-up stating that I already have the latest verion which is true, but there seems to be no way to change my version with the debug one.
AS anyone succeed in using the debug version of flash undex one of these browser on Windows 10 (64bits)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Currently the answer is no, you can not use the Flash debugger in Windows 10 / IE or Edge browsers as they are 'embedded' libraries in the OS now. The options are to use Win 10 & Firefox or use Win 8.1 when debugging Flash.

Via: https://forums.adobe.com/message/7841726#7841726

> I have received confirmation that at this time Microsoft does not
>   support the debuggers on Windows 10.  We do not have an estimate as to
>   when they will support the debuggers, but when they do, the install
>   links will be added to the Adobe Flash Player Support Center page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robert.

Comment: np, hopefully Microsoft and Adobe figure something out soon to allow devs to use the debug versions... I understand not allowing external plugins in Edge, but the fact that you can not change the IE version is tough to deal with.

Comment: Please see my answer. Otherwise, you will be waiting a long time for Adobe/Microsoft to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it manually by yourself, the core step is running flash_debugger installation file with switch -install, after a few modification in debugger folder, then you might reach there.
showing the happy result in image following.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmHEs.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Where did you find the documentation? Can you provide a link or a small modus operandi?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the windows 7 virtual machine for free. I recommend Virtual Box. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/
2. Once you have Windows 7 running inside Windows 10, install the IE Flash debugger or another of your choice. https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 does not support flash player content debugging in windows 10.Fire fox and Chrome browsers however allow for the content debugging in windows 10.

1)**Install Flash debugger for Firefox or Chrome:**

```
a)  Go to  https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html
b) For fire fox, Download and install Download the Flash Player content debugger for Firefox - NPAPI 
c)  For Chrome, Download and install  Download the Flash Player content debugger for Opera and Chromium based applications – PPAPI
```